# Matrix norms and spectral radius

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, spectral-radius

Recently I started exploring convergence of some iterative methods and spotted the equivalent of the spectral radius and *a* matrix norm.

For instance, http://www.scribd.com/doc/37323755/36/Richardson-Iteration states in Example 1.28 that 2-norm of a matrix is its spectral radius. On the other hand, [What is the difference between the Frobenius norm and the 2-norm of a matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33083/what-is-the-difference-between-the-frobenius-norm-and-the-2-norm-of-a-matrix) states a difference.

What is the difference between the Frobenius and 2-norm of a matrix? Is the class of *symmetric* matrices for which the equality of 2-norm and the spectral radius holds?

Comment: Frobenius norm is a matrix norm while 2-norm is a vector norm. The 2-norm of a matrix is defined in terms of vectors 2-norm (look for the definition). On the other hand matrix norms are defined (axiomatically) directly for matrices.

Comment: @fmoura2005 What is then 2-norm of a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$? What is its relation to the spectral radius of $A$?

Comment: $\|A\|_2=\max\|Ax\|_2$, over $\|x\|_2=1$. This max coincides with maximum singular value of $A$. This, by the way, answer your question about the symmetric matrices. In general, the spectral radius is less or equal than the matrix norm.

Comment: Thanks; it would be good if you could make a formal answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. Regarding your first question, the difference I see is that Frobenius norm is a matrix norm while a matrix 2-norm is induced by the vector 2-norm, i.e.,
$\|A\|_2=\max_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|_2$. In fact, $\|A\|_2$ is the maximal singular value of $A$, that is, the square root of the maximal eingenvalue of $A^TA$ (this more computable). This also answer your second question. In general the spectral radius of a matrix is less or equal than the matrix norm.

Comment: Could you explain why the matrix 2-norm is also equal to the square root of the maximal eigenvalue of A^TA?

Comment: @ClausW. Oh Yes. In fact, since $A^TA$ is symetric, it has an ortornormal set of eingenvectors (which is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$). So, you can easily deduce that $\max\frac{x^TA^TAx}{x^Tx}$ is exactly the maximum eigenvalue of $A^TA$ (this is the Rayleigh quotient); but $\max\frac{x^TA^TAx}{x^Tx}$ is $\|A\|^2$!

Comment: Why would $||A||_2$ be the square root of the maximum singular value of A? I thought it is directly equal to the max. singular value of A.

Comment: @OndrejSkopek This was clearly a mistake, which is now corrected in the edit.