# Discrete fourier transform and Frobenius norm

Tags: fourier-analysis, discrete-mathematics, normed-spaces

I have thousands of data files which are essential DFT data of plots such as this:

[image]

And a DFT of the plot with a "Hard" [threshold](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Threshold.html) of 0.9 gives me:

[image]

This DFT is just the left top corner of the DFT data with the DC value removed.

The reason I used a threshold value of `0.9` is because in the DFT coefficient matrix that I plotted above, most of the values of very small (~10^-4) and there are maybe 1-2 values that influence the DFT and they are above `0.9`

However, it was suggested that I use a `Frobenius Norm` of my DFT data to threshold my plots.

Why is that? I can't use a Frob. norm as a threshold because it is a very large value ~100 and my DFT coefficient matrix is populated with numbers <100 generally

Should I just divide my DFT data with the Frob. norm?
I have read the following posts 
[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54176/is-there-a-geometric-meaning-of-the-frobenius-norm)
[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33083/what-is-the-difference-between-the-frobenius-norm-and-the-2-norm-of-a-matrix)
[3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/fourier-transform-for-dummies)

~Concerned Mechanical engineer

Comment: How are you defining the Frobenius norm?

Comment: I am not. [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Norm.html) is. I just plan on using the Frob Norm for my work.